# How to include a multipage table from an external file

Tags: tables, longtable, standalone

I usually save my tables as standalone PDFs, generated by compiling a `standalone` document and then include them in the main file via `\includegraphics{pdf.name}`

However, I now have a two-pages table made with `longtable` and I would like to include it with the same method, saving it as a separate PDF and then including it with `includegraphics`.

This does not seem to work and has many issues:

1. `standalone` class do not work with `longtable`s
2. If I save the table as a normal `article` then it can't be included with `includegraphics`

So my question is: How should I proceed to include a multi-page table from an external file? Is it even possible?

Comment: Use `standalone` with `article` option when you are building the long table. In the main input file load `docmute` package, and import the table via `\input` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a perfect application of the [`standalone`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) bundle.

You can store your [`longtable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/longtable) `table` in (say), `mytablefile.tex`, and then `input` it into your main file using `input`.

Here are two files that demonstrate the idea- note that `mytablefile.tex` uses the `standalone` *documentclass* while `mainfile.tex` uses `standalone` *package*. This is a very simple demonstration, but you can do some more sophisticated things- explore the [`manual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) and this site for more details.

Note that with your current approach your table will not inherit the font style of your main document- furthermore, it will likely be scaled and may look out of place- the technique I have demonstrated does not have this problem.

## `mainfile.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\input{mytablefile}
\end{document}
```

## `mytablefile.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, worked. As a small side question, this is doable only including the .tex file directly, it would not be possible to do with a pdf, is this correct?

Comment: @JackO including the `pdf` suffers from the drawbacks detailed in my answer; if you generate a 'stand alone' pdf file, you will have to insert the breaks yourself, perhaps using the `pdfpages` packages or something similar.