# imported table positioning

Tags: tables, positioning, aastex

I am importing a data table into a document and want the table to be within the text. When I import with `\input{bodyrate}[htpb]`, the table is placed at the end of the document and `[htpb]` is printed instead. How do I get the table to be where I import it in the .tex file?

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\begin{document}
\input{file}[htpb]
\end{document}
```

the table file begins with:

```
\begin{deluxetable}{lccc}
\tablecolumns{4}
\tablewidth{0pc}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: "You're doing it wrong..." `\input{<file>}` literally just places the contents of `<file>` at the location where you call `\input` *and* takes no optional arguments. The reason for pushing your table to the end of the document could be because it is too large to fit on the given page, leaving behind only the "fake" optional arguments you specify `[htpb]`.

Comment: It doesn't just go to the next page though, it goes to the very end of the document, skipping over other parts of the document.

Comment: So how do I specify that I want it in the next available space where I locate it in the tex file, not at the end of the document?

Comment: @unknown: How big is the table when you look at where TeX placed it at the end of your document? Does it fit within the text block boundary? If not, then that's the reason why it's pushed to the end. If it does fit, then the question is whether you have other floats hanging around? Does `file.tex` contain a `table` environment? If so, add your optional arguments to *that* environment, not the `\input` command.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts (one on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2483176/user2483176) and one on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42841/unknown)). The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I recently answered a similar question [How to include a multipage table from an external file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150085) Perhaps it will help

Answer (score 1):

You should always include a complete document in your question (and please don't just ask the same question again) however you can always stop a float floating by using `\clearpage` so

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\begin{document}
text
\clearpage
\input{file}
\clearpage
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To input a floating table, which appears at the next available space, you should use the `table` environment.

```
\begin{table}
  \input{bodyrate} % Here you put the actual table.
\end{table}
```

The `h`, `t`, `b` and `p` arguments specify where the table can be located on a page. By using all four, you indicate that it can be placed anywhere. The same effect is achieved by not using any at all.

Comment: I tried that, but I got the error LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode

Comment: @unknown What exactly does the file bodyrate contain? I mean let us know the structure of that file. What is the first command it contains?

Comment: okay, I added that to my question above.