# save table on a separate file

Tags: tables

I'm new to LaTeX.
I have a table in the LaTeX format that I want to include in my document. Since it is a large table, I would like to save it in a different file and then just load it in my main document.

How can I do this?

Comment: if your table is already formated in LaTeX, just save it in any .tex file and use `\input{yourtable}` in main tex. If your table only contains raw data use `pgfplotstable` (part of [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)) package to include and process it from the external file. If you provide an example, you will get more accurate solutions.

Comment: you can find a complete MWE of what @Ignasi describes in my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150085/how-to-include-a-multipage-table-from-an-external-file, for example

Comment: Or you could include it using e.g. pdfpages if it is in a stable state and you want to avoid re-compiling it all the time. (Or maybe the standalone package can do this better? I've only just discovered its existence, though, so I'm unclear of its capabilities at present.)

Answer (score 18):

Your question doesn't explain how is your table except that it's large and that you would like to save on a different file, but you don't say if it's already formatted like a `tabular` or only contains `raw` data.

If your external file (`table.tex`) is already formatted, something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
a & b & c \\
aa & bb & cc \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

you just have to `\input` it in your text where you want. The command to be used is `\input{name-of-your-file}`.

But if your file only contains data with no `LaTeX` formatting commands, there exist several packages to process and format it in your document. One of these packages is [`pgfplotstable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) which is part of `pgfplots`.

As an example suppose that your data file (`table-raw.txt`) contains:

```
A B C 
a b c 
aa bb cc
```

with command `\pgfplotstabletypeset[formatting options]{table-raw.txt}`  you can process and typeset its contents during your text compilation.

Next code shows and example with both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

File \texttt{table.tex} contains an already formatted \LaTeX\ tabular. 
To include it in your text just use \verb+\input{table.tex}+: where you want it.

\begin{center}
\input{table.tex}
\end{center}


File \texttt{table-raw.txt} contains some data organized in rows and columns. 
Its \LaTeX\ format will be generated with  \texttt{pgfplotstable} help.

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
   every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, 
                             after row=\midrule},
   every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
   col sep=space, 
   header=true, 
   string type]{table-raw.txt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My table is being forced to go on a new page, and I have given no such commands in the table.tex file. Any fix?

Comment: @Man, probably your table is forced to go on a new page because there is no enough space for it in present page. A `tabular` can not be broken between pages. If you need to break it I think you'll need `longtable`.

Comment: `\begin{table}\input{tablefile}\end{table}` would be better if OP wants a floating table.

Comment: it's not clear from the answer whether we can refer to `\label{name_in_file}` from the main document, though I assume it's the case?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm not sure to ubderstand your question, but I hope [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358560/input-tex-file-with-its-references-to-outer-scope) helps you. Otherwise, ask a new question. I think yours is not related with this one.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221069/2849383) by @Werner on the main StackOverflow website worked very well for me using `catchfile` package, so I copied it here.

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
%table.tex
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Table test.

1. Insert a full table

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & b \\
  \hline
  c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

2. Input the body of table from a separate file

\CatchFileDef{\mytable}{table.tex}{}% table.tex > \mytable
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
  \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```