# How do you import a text file into a longtable?

Tags: tables

I have a rather large text file that I'm trying to convert into a table. I'm pretty new to Latex, so I was using this other answer from this site as a guide to help me:

[save table on a separate file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150829/save-table-on-a-separate-file?newreg=2eae996cc61e4999a45d39c6250ff147)

and I got some great results, but I realized that my table needs to be split up across many pages, which they say to use `longtable` to achieve. I don't completely understand where you would add that in or which part you would replace with that, and I was hoping that someone could explain that to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do import a text file (`pgfplotstable` or `datatool` packages might help with that) but unless the text is being generated many times and you need to continuously import I wouldn't do that.

If you have a text file (say comma separated values)

```
a, b, c
1, 3, 7
xx, yy, zz
```

then just use your normal text editor to change `,` to `&` and put `\\` at ends of lines:

```
   \begin{longtable}{ccc}
    a& b& c\\
    1& 3& 7\\
    xx& yy& zz
   \end{longtable}
```

Then you are done, it's already a legal LaTeX table.

You can later add column formatting and commands to add header to each page, and captions etc, but that can be added later as part of your general document editing.