# Input .tex file with its references to outer scope

Tags: input

Assume I have a dissertation file `diss.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{one}
\section{Two} \label{sec 2}
This is section two.
\end{document}
```

which inputs section one from the outer file `one.tex`

```
\section{One}
This is section one with a reference to section \ref{sec 2}
```

Note that in `diss.tex` there is a reference to section two. Compilation of `diss.tex` works out fine. Now I want another file (synopsis) `syn.tex` to be precisely the same as `section 1` of my dissertation file. If I just do that

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is synopsis.
\input{one} 
\end{document}
```

The link to `section two` will be broken (displayed as ??). Is there a way to remedy this? In principle I do not mind loading the whole `section two` into synopsis unless I do not have to display its contents.

Comment: You want reference section two, without display section two in your document?

Comment: @Bobyandbob exactly. So that when I restructure the `diss.tex` file and section 2 becomes say section 3, I do not have to do any corrections to `syn.tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your short document load the `xr` package and reference the full document in `\externaldocument`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{diss}
\begin{document}
This is synopsis.
\input{one} 
\end{document}
```