# Saving all tables in separate file

Tags: tables, multiple-files

Is there a way I can save all my `tabular` formatted tables in a separate a file and call them wherever they are needed. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150829/save-table-on-a-separate-file) discusses it for single table but I need for multiple.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you want them in the same file (`all_tables.tbl`) or in several files (`table1.tbl`, `table2.tbl`, ...)?
Several files would be easier to work with IMHO, you could put them in a subfolder to not have a lot of extra files in the project directory. Both cases are possible to achieve though

Comment: I want them in one single file.

Comment: I do not know what a `.tbl` file is.

Comment: @pkj each file can have the extension you choose. If you want to call a file `foo.wobble` go ahead and do so. Here `tbl` was chosen as the extension to tell the visitor of the containing folder that those are tables (`tbl` seems like an abbreviation for table, doesn't it?).

Comment: @pkj You could put every table in one file and surround each one with a Boolean construct, to make sure only that one is used when you input the file. But I think the needed infrastructure to do this isn't worth it.

Comment: @Skillmon: thanks, I thought `.tbl` is some TeX supported file format for saving tables

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about tables, it's possible to have a file (say `mytables.sty`) in which each table is defined to be a command say `\mytableA`,`\mytableB` etc (just surround the normal table markup by `\newcommand\mytableB{....}`

Then you can use `\usepackage{mytables}`  and `\mytableB` in any document that needs `\myTableB`.

But if there are a lot of tables in the file you impose the time cost of reading the file, and the memory cost of storing all the definitions, and obscure the document by hiding the table content, so it isn't clearly a win.

Comment: thank you, it is very close to what I was expecting