# ! Misplaced \noalign. \bottomrule error with \estauto \estwide

Tags: stata

I am using the following Stata code to create a table with three regression models.

```
esttab model_E1* using "C_1_NM.tex", replace booktabs fragment alignment(S) varwidth(25) nomtitles label nobaselevels star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) eqlabels(none)
```

The resulting C_1_NM.tex file is

```
                         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         \\
\midrule
x1                      &      -0.143\sym{**} &     -0.0191         &      0.0176         \\
                         &     (-2.32)         &     (-0.32)         &      (0.05)         \\
\addlinespace
x2                &      -0.818\sym{***}&       0.887\sym{***}&       32.13\sym{***}\\
                         &     (-7.78)         &      (9.14)         &     (56.79)         \\
\addlinespace
x1 $\times$ x2   &     -0.0864         &      -0.149\sym{**} &      -12.42\sym{***}\\
                         &     (-1.18)         &     (-2.02)         &    (-24.75)         \\
\addlinespace
x3             &      -4.037\sym{***}&       6.329\sym{***}&       10.86\sym{**} \\
                         &     (-4.80)         &      (5.62)         &      (2.08)         \\
\addlinespace
x4          &     0.00180         &      -0.111\sym{***}&    -0.00565         \\
                         &      (0.05)         &     (-4.33)         &     (-0.03)         \\
\addlinespace
x5             &       0.371\sym{***}&       0.264\sym{***}&      -0.119         \\
                         &     (22.04)         &     (14.32)         &     (-0.91)         \\
\addlinespace
x6                 &      0.0149         &      0.0601\sym{**} &       0.287         \\
                         &      (0.52)         &      (2.31)         &      (1.24)         \\
\addlinespace
x7       &      -0.626         &      -0.473         &       2.455         \\
                         &     (-1.11)         &     (-0.80)         &      (0.39)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant                 &       1.258\sym{***}&      -0.537\sym{***}&       13.56\sym{***}\\
                         &      (8.95)         &     (-3.95)         &     (10.28)         \\
\addlinespace
FE1        &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\addlinespace
FE2                  &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\midrule
Observations             &        1503         &        1503         &        1503         \\
```

Next I am running the manuscript.tex file below

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear,nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs} % in order to automatically refer to the tables created in LaTeX - see \input{•} below.
\usepackage{lscape} % to create landscape tables
\usepackage{standalone} % needed for longtable - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150085/how-to-include-a-multipage-table-from-an-external-file
\usepackage{longtable} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150085/how-to-include-a-multipage-table-from-an-external-file
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}% For Notes below table

\makeatletter
\let\c@author\relax
\makeatother

% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}% Thanks to David Carlisle

\let\estinput=\input% define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
    \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
\newcommand{\figtext}[1]{
    \vspace{-1.9ex}
    \captionsetup{justification=justified,font=footnotesize}
    \caption*{\hspace{6pt}\hangindent=1.5em #1}
    }
\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}

% Add significance note with \starnote
\newcommand{\starnote}{\figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
        input-signs     = ,
        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        }

\begin{document}

blahblahblah...........

\clearpage

% Table 7
\begin{table}
\caption{Regression}
\estauto{C_1_NM}{3}{S[table-format=4.4]}
\starnote
\label{tab7}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

but am getting the following error

> ! Misplaced \noalign.
> \bottomrule ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
> l.486 \estauto{C_1_NM}{3}{S[table-format=4.4]}
> I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
> an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

Can you please advise what I should do? The error is clearly related to \estauto (and possibly \estwide) in the preamble. I have adapted the code from https://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code appears to require an external file (called `desc.tex`?) that only you have. Please make your code more readily compilable.

Comment: @Mico I have edited the MWE. I am still getting the error. Can you please let me know why that is the case? Thanks.

Comment: are you asking about "Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'e'."?

Comment: Incidentally, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with `\estauto`, `\estwide`, etc are. Sorry, but my mind-reading capabilities are worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem can be found here:

[Problems with \input{table.tex}\hline after 2020 fall LaTeX release](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567985/problems-with-inputtable-tex-hline-after-2020-fall-latex-release)

You need to replace "\let\estinput=\input" with "\let\estinput=@@input"

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas. I am now getting the error message `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` I don't understand as it is clearly below the preamble.

Comment: Try using the \makeatletter command:  
``
\makeatletter %this is needed to allow latex to revert to prior installations to fix noalign error
\let\estinput=\@@input %define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{ %estwide environment
 \vspace{.75ex}{
  \begin{tabular*}
  {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
  \toprule
  \estinput{#1}
  \bottomrule
  \addlinespace[.75ex]
  \end{tabular*}
  }
 }
``

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas. Your solution worked. I appreciate your help. I actually came across the link you sent a few days ago as I was looking for a solution but did not pay much attention to it.

Comment: I have just discovered that Stata 17 (i.e. the latest version) has improved the functionality of the -table- command. I have not read the post yet but it may be an alternative to -esttab- to export tables to LaTeX. Here is the link: https://www.stata.com/stata-news/news36-3/customizable-tables/